# Can I run 2 sessions with 2 displays on windows server 2008 R2?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-server-2008-r2, kodi, multiple-users

Can I connect 2 displays to my PC and configure it to log in under 2 different accounts and show them on different displays?

My goal is to connect 2 TVs to 1 PC and run different media servers (xbmc/kodi) there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one way to do it would be via RDC. Open two separate sessions, connect to localhost and log in. You can then display each session on separate screen. It is highly manual, though - Windows remembers which screen the application should use as default, but as long as you use two instances of same application this won't work. So no remote to set up that satisfactorily, I think.

Tested on Server2012. Initial tests say it looks like working.

Comment: yes, that would work, but performance will not be very good. As I mentioned that I would like to run media center there and performance of the video via RDP is far away from good.

Comment: So the other way would be to use VDI on the server, but this is a bit outside my experience. And I have no idea how it's performing when multimedia are involved, also it, I think, requires extra licensing...